# How do I get rid of photos labeled "My Computer" on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos

I've been trying to clear up some space on my iPhone, and recently I noticed that I have a few albums labeled from My Computer.

I've tried going through iTunes, but my phone doesn't seem to sync up to it, and there's nothing in the setting that will let me get rid of them. I can't even find the actual pictures on my computer, so I have no idea what to do. It's gotten to the point where these pictures are annoying me. I think they were once used as backgrounds, but I can't find the folders or anything.

Comment: Do you have photos labeled "My Computer" or albums labeled "My Computer".  The body doesn't match the question.
Also, Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, I'd sync with 'Image Capture' instead of 'iTunes' to delete any unwanted photos.